# Is it possible to do transpositions of big.matrix objects from the bigmemory package?

Tags: r, r-bigmemory

I would like to perform a transpose of a very large bigmemory big.matrix *B* so that I can compute *AB*<sup>*T*</sup>. Is this possible in bigmemory? And more importantly how can I find documation about this? On page 5 of this paper on bigmemory http://www.stat.yale.edu/~mjk56/temp/bigmemory-vignette.pdf, the authors say the package also supports operations such as prod(), colmean(), colsd(), etc, but I cannot locate documentation on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That documentation is rather old at this point and is rapidly becoming more so.  I am one of the current developers of the bigmemory packages.  We have begun quite a few new updates to the bigmemory package to make it more modern and accessible.  We hope to be releasing a new updated version to CRAN shortly.

That said, the transpose functionality is actually to be part of the `bigalgebra` package.  At the moment, it is under heavy development where I have been working on extending the functions to include more simple functions like `t`.  Fair warning, there is a good chance you will find a bug or two.  So, after talking perhaps too much here is a potential solution.

Install my current development branch of `bigalgebra`

```
library(devtools)
# probably also install dev bigmemory
# install_github("kaneplusplus/bigmemory")
install_github('cdeterman/bigalgebra')
```

This will provide you with the `t` method for `big.matrix` objects.

```
library(bigalgebra)
set.seed(123)
bm <- as.big.matrix(matrix(rnorm(25), nrow=5))
bm[]
            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,] -0.56047565  1.7150650  1.2240818  1.7869131 -1.0678237
[2,] -0.23017749  0.4609162  0.3598138  0.4978505 -0.2179749
[3,]  1.55870831 -1.2650612  0.4007715 -1.9666172 -1.0260044
[4,]  0.07050839 -0.6868529  0.1106827  0.7013559 -0.7288912
[5,]  0.12928774 -0.4456620 -0.5558411 -0.4727914 -0.6250393

t(bm)[]
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]       [,5]
[1,] -0.5604756 -0.2301775  1.5587083  0.07050839  0.1292877
[2,]  1.7150650  0.4609162 -1.2650612 -0.68685285 -0.4456620
[3,]  1.2240818  0.3598138  0.4007715  0.11068272 -0.5558411
[4,]  1.7869131  0.4978505 -1.9666172  0.70135590 -0.4727914
[5,] -1.0678237 -0.2179749 -1.0260044 -0.72889123 -0.6250393
```

One follow-up point, you seem to be specifically interested in the `tcrossprod` of two matrices.  I will keep this in mind to create the respective binding in the `bigalgebra` package.

Comment: A version of tcrossprod for big.matrix sounds great!

Comment: Also a related question, what is the state of element-wise matrix multiplication with your current master branch?  I saw you've added that to the Arith group generic for big.matrix.  Is it safe to try out or still experimental?

Comment: @andrew, element-wise multiplication should be functional.  I say everything is experimental because I am working on setting up the backend to rely on RcppArmadillo to improve the interface with alternate BLAS/LAPACK libraries.  As such, much of the backend code is occasionally in flux.  You should be safe right now as I haven't had too much time recently to devote to it unfortunately.

Comment: At least for the current version of bigalgebra, the right syntax for transposing is `t(bm[])`.